Okhttp Caching requests depending of them url and headers values
I have couple requests that return different results depending of header value. I implement caching mechanism for them and its working fine for different urls but okhttp is probably take only urls (without the headers values) so I got the same result for different header values.
Is there a way to force OkHttp to take in consideration headers as well? It can be just one value of the header.
Example:
1. "https/domain/items" Header - ShopId=123 
2. "https/domain/items" Header - ShopId=124

For instance I cache response 1 go to screen which use request 2 cache that data as well and go back to screen 1 and try to get cached data - I will obtain request 2 data
Unfortunately I cannot change how API works.
I think about overriding CacheStrategy in okhttp lib but honestly don't know how to do it and whats more use it in the client

What do you mean by but okhttp is probably take only urls (without the headers values)? Are you checking the headers of the response? and show the code you wrote so far.

Get the server to set the Vary header on the HTTP response.
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 100
Vary: ShopId
...

If the server’s owners refuse, you can rewrite the server’s HTTP response in a network interceptor to add that header on its behalf. (But then their cache will be broken for other user agents, such as web browsers.)
